# Unable to access nested data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I noticed I cannot access to a nested js object.

`this.DB.get(2)` returns an object in the form

```
{
id:1,
name: "my title",
Obj:{en:"english",fr:"french"}
}
```

This is the component

```
export default class Item extends Component {

    state = {
        Item:{}
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.DB = $DB()
        this.setState({
            Item: this.DB.get(2)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const id = params ? params.id : null;
        const Item = this.state.Item
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                Number field: {Item.id} | 
                String field: {Item.name} |
                Object field: <FlatList data={Object.entries(Item.Obj)} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**The problem: I cannot access to `Item.Obj`.**

I got it, `setState` is async, I'm not sure this is causing the issue though. Anyway: is there a clean way for render the component in setState callback?

**edit**: I've just rebuilt (still in debug mode) and now it works, I do not changed anything, just added some `console.log()` around.

Anyway, I don't feel so safe. setState() is async and still I see around the web this function used wildly as it would be sync.
If the data I want to render are in the state, is there a way to render the component *always* after the state update?

Another doubt: you see the Component, it just does an access to a big JS object and shows some data and that's all. Do I really need to pass through the component state? 
What do you think if I would move those 2 lines inside the `render()` method?

```
const DB = $DB()
const Item = DB.get(2)
```

Comment: Add default state inside the constructor (below super call), then you should access via `this.state.Item `

Comment: If you successfully set the state React will re-render the component. constructor is unnecessary here but should not be the problem. Is $DB() async? Return promise or something? Can't you just access Item.Obj? What about others like Item.id?

Comment: $DB() is not async (it is a plain js function containing some `require("data.json")`). I can access `Item.id` and `Item.name` (side question, I honestly don't get what that `constructor` with `super()` does).

Comment: What is the result of a simple `console.log( this.state.Item.Obj )` in render? super is for reaching some stuff of parent object in JS classes.

Comment: I edited the question with some progress

Comment: I did not understand your setState question? React re-render the component every state changes. Do you mean first render and you are worried about no data at this time? Then render your component conditionally, if there is no data return something like spinner, after getting data return something else. This is most of people how handle the render. How do you get this big JS object?

Comment: @devserkan yep you understood correctly. And yes, maybe I will go with an `ActivityIndicator` while loading. The strange fact I still do not understand, I wasted hours before open this question, then the same code launched again began to work..maybe RN have some kind of inner caching?
The second doubt I'm talking about in the question is: do I really need to use component state in this case? maybe I could move the whole DB access in `render()` method...

Comment: If so, then consider conditional rendering definitely. Maybe we can move those discussion into chat but I'm a newbie and also need to go now :)